# ngx-cookieconsent is not working in angular universal(SSR) Server Build

Tags: angular

I have implemented `ngx-cookieconsent` in Angular(version `8.1.3`) Project and it is working on local with `ng serve` and `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`. Cookie pop up is working fine but same build is not working on server (alicloud).

Answer (score 0):

Use it only in the browser:

```
[... ]

constructor(
  private readonly injector: Injector,
  @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
) {
    if (!isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      this.injector.get(NgcCookieConsentService);
    }
  }

[...]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, i implemented this also but it is not working. i don't understand what i am missing?

Comment: Can you create a project on stackblitz.com so I can see what you’re doing? Just a bare angular project with ngx-cookieconsent